# Uploading new design on canvas

Tags: canvas, facebook-canvas

I have hosted my design:- http://www.gavinwynne.co.uk/facebook/index.html

and used the tutorial to upload as an ap in facebook.

But when I go to test: https://apps.facebook.com/gavinwynne/
I receive an error message within facebook: "Secure Connection Failed", (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Any help would be much appreciated

Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to serve your canvas page through HTTPS in order to have a Facebook canvas app since October 1st

See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/

Comment: how do I serve through HTTPS ?

Comment: You'll have to contact your hosting company, but you'll have to purchase an SSL certificate. They can help you set it up on your server.

Comment: Found SSL/TLS Manager on my cpanel. is that what i need to do ?

Comment: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache-cpanel.htm should help you. You'll need to purchase an SSL certificate from somewhere

Comment: in xilo-cpanel, I can adjust and add SSL security. At the moment I have no security on, so not sure why im having an issue ?

Comment: Facebook only allows applications to be served over HTTPS rather than HTTP

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gavinwynne.co.uk/facebook/index.html  I cannot access https version of your site in a browser regardless of facebook or not.  You will need to have your server admin check the server settings.

Comment: I host with xilo, can I adjust server settings in cpanel ?

Comment: Found SSL/TLS Manager on my cpanel. is that what i need to do ?

Comment: I would presume so, however you will need to contact your server administrator to fix the SSL issue.  I'm not a server admin.  ;)